# flutter vs android native in battery consumption & apk size?

Tags: flutter

I can see some buzz around flutter. Lot of people write about it, but I can't get actual answer to these questions:

- How does battery consumption of native android (Java) app & a flutter app compare? Does it help that flutter compiles to native code? (correct me if I am wrong)
- How larger are flutter apps compared to native java apps? Is the size difference consistent or does it scale up with size / functionality of the app?

Answer (score 1):

> How does battery consumption of native android (Java) app & a flutter app compare? Does it help that flutter compiles to native code? (correct me if I am wrong)

Battery consumption depends on the type of app you're creating. It's not like that the apps built with Flutter eat a lot of battery. And yes, Flutter compiles to native code.

> How larger are flutter apps compared to native java apps? Is the size difference consistent or does it scale up with size / functionality of the app?

Size of a simple `Hello World` app in Android is around 4.06 MB and for iOS it is 10.8 MB. You can find more info [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16833).

Comment: I think I had to clarify -- for an average app, (not game -- say a stack overflow client), does writing in flutter be more battery consuming than native?

Comment: There is no clear evidence yet, but I don't think it would consume more battery than a native app.